# I need to output FORM variables to a report, but only if there is a value

Tags: coldfusion

I have a form with many values in it (around 25 fields).  After the form is posted and inserted into the database, I have to take the form information and output it to a report.  The report should only show fields with those that have values in it (so the report would only have 5 fields in it, if only 5 fields were filled in).

The easiest way would be to do something like this:

```
<cfif form.firstname neq "">
    <li><First Name: #FORM.FIRSTNAME#</li>
</cfif>
<cfif form.lastname neq "">
    <li><Last Name: #FORM.LASTNAME#</li>
</cfif>
```

Can anyone recommend a better way of doing this?  I would like to keep it on the ColdFusion side, since the entire report is stripped of HTML to produce a plain text report as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through them like this

```
<cfloop list="#form.fieldNames#" index="i">
    <li><cfoutput>#i# = #form[i]#</cfoutput></li>
</cfloop>
```

Not sure that is exactly what you want but it might get you on the right track

**Based on your comment** try this :

```
<cfloop list="#form.fieldNames#" index="i">
    <li><cfoutput>
        <cfswitch expression="#i#">
            <cfcase value="firstName">
                First Name 
            </cfcase>
            <cfcase value="lastName">
                Last Name 
            </cfcase>
            <cfdefaultcase>
                #i#
            </cfdefaultcase>
        </cfswitch>
      : #form[i]#</cfoutput></li>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: That looks promising.  I might end up doing something like that.  Unfortunately, the field names aren't as descriptive as I would like it, but it might have to do.

Comment: using array notation is preferable to using the evaluate function.

Comment: Now check for the length of form[1] so you don't output blank fields.

Comment: Downvoted because there are multiple things wrong with the first code snippet, most specifically evaluate is not just "not preferable"; it is bad practise in almost all situations. Also `'#i#'` as well as lack of HTML encoding.

Comment: Well, Lance definitely pointed me in the right direction.  My solution below:

Comment: Interesting 2 down votes at least Peter left a comment even though it was a comment that was regarding something that wasn't even in the answer at the time he left the comment (makes no sense but..ok).  @Chester this wasn't meant to do the job for you it was meant to help get you on the right track and I am glad it did.  I am happy to add something constructive that you found helpful

Comment: Er, it was and still is in the answer. You might have appended more content, but your initial bad example is still there, as the first thing others see on an accepted answer, so it's a good thing the vote score warns people to be wary.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt at this:  Thanks to Lance for pointing me towards the right direction:

```
<ul>
    <cfoutput>
    <cfloop list="#form.fieldNames#" index="i">
    <li>
        <cfif len(trim(form[i])) neq 0>
        <cfswitch expression="#i#">
            <cfcase value="FIRST_NAME">First Name</cfcase>
            <cfcase value="LAST_NAME">Last Name</cfcase>
            <cfdefaultcase>#i#</cfdefaultcase>
        </cfswitch>
        : #FORM[i]#
        </cfif>
    </li>   
    </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to using switch/case - put labels in a struct

```
<cfset FieldLabels = 
    { 'first_name'  : "First Name"
    , 'last_name'   : "Last Name"
    , 'other stuff' : "Whatever you like"
    }/>

<cfoutput>
    <ul>
        <cfloop index="CurField" list=#Form.FieldNames# >
            <cfif len(trim( Form[CurField] )) >
                <li>
                    #StructKeyExists( FieldLabels , lcase(CurField) )
                        ? FieldLabels[ lcase(CurField) ]
                        : HtmlEditFormat( replace(CurField,'_',' ','all') )
                    #
                    : #HtmlEditFormat( Form[CurField] )#
                </li>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </ul>
</cfoutput>
```

Note that it does not do `neq 0` on the len - this is entirely unnecessary.

The `a ? b : c` construct inside the first hashes is the ternary conditional operator - a compact way of doing if/else - supported in CF10 and Railo 3.3 onwards.

If a name doesn't have an explicit label, it replaces underscores with spaces, which is probably preferable if the report is for a non-technical audience.

If it's possible that you have code that adds (or removes) items in the form scope without modifying the FieldNames list, you can change the loop for this...

```
<cfloop item="CurField" collection=#Form# >
    <cfif CurField EQ 'FieldNames'>
        <cfcontinue />
    </cfif>
    ...
```

Which looks at the actual keys in the Form scope - though the ordering of them is not guaranteed for this method.

Answer (score 0):

How about you loop on the struct itself directly ?

```
<cfscript>    
for(eachKey in FORM){
    if(FORM[eachKey] neq ''){
        writeOutput('<li>' & 
                    FORM[eachKey] & ' = ' &
                    trim( FORM[eachKey] ) &
                   '</li>');
    }
}
</cfscript>
```

You can have a space in the form variable name.